# how to take the first letters in Mysql request

Tags: mysql

I have an `sql request`, that contains 3 parameters:

```
Article   Name_customer  id_customer.
```

My request is:

```
select "Article", "Client", "Name", round(sum("Montant_fac_eur")) as turnover
from "foundry_sync"."data"
where "Nature"='Repair' 

and "annee" = {{w_widget24.selectedValue}}

and extract(month from "Facturation") between 0+{{w_widget4.selectedValue}} and 2+{{w_widget4.selectedValue}}
--and "Facturation" = {{w_widget6.selectedValue}}
group by "Article", "Client", "Name"
order by turnover DESC limit 5
```

I used the `id_customer` in the axis of abscissa, but I want change it by the name.
The problem is the name of my customers are long.
Can I do a test on the name to take just the 5 first letters, to display it in my dashboard ?

PS.: Knowing that I have some names are similarly, looks like:

```
AEROSPARES 2000 LTD
AEROSPARES SHANNON
```

Thanks

Comment: _to take just the 5 first letters_ What if 1 customers name is _Thoma_ and another 1 is _Thomas_?

Comment: You have a right. So, how can I do it if I have this case ?

Comment: you seem to be trying to fix a display issue by changing data.  Shouldn't you fix display at the Presentation layer not the Data layer?  you said the data is too long: well is it more acceptable to display a portion of the data (name), have what appear to be duplicates, merge data, use an ID_customer instead of name, use the FEIN of the customer?

Comment: @xQbert No, I don't have the access to change the data at the Presentation.

Comment: I edited my question, I gived you an example, sometimes we do not find just the 5 letters. Thanks

Comment: IMO you are not addressing the root cause correctly.  Your attempt to fix it will likely result in additional errors.  As @bub pointed out. If you shorten the names they may no longer be unique thus you can't interpret the data. To keep the data quality you could concat some letters from name in addition to the customer_ID; that way you get a hint at the name while maintaining uniqueness.  This assumes you have space to add some letters to the ID in the display.  But the real fix is to edit the display; and even then you could have duplicates on name unless you have a unique index on that col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function as follows to select the first 5 characters of `id_customer`

```
SELECT LEFT(`id_customer`, 5)...
```